# Automapper Ignore Auto Flattening

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a Entity in a legacy system which has the format

```
public Guid Id {get;set;}
public int Duration {get;set;}
public bool DurationType {get;set;}
```

In a ViewModel I have the following

```
public Guid Id {get; set;}
public int Duration {get;set;}
```

Mapping from The Entity to the View Model works fine, however when I try and map from the ViewModel to the Entity it dies.

What it appears to be doing is trying to call a non existing property Duration.Type in the reverse mapping (i.e it's trying to auto-flatten). This results in the error `Cannot map int32 to bool`.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to disable auto-flattening in AutoMapper or manually set the fields which maps happen to using attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have it ignore the `DurationType` property when mapping from `ViewModel` to `Entity` add this to your mapping configuration:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModel,Entity>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.DurationType, options => options.Ignore());
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it via attributes (just seems a little cleaner) if not, no worries.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I've always controlled done it this way.